# TikZ matrix delimiters are too big

Tags: tikz-pgf, delimiters, tikz-matrix

I want to make a matrix with TikZ so I can put some fancy colored boxes around some elements, but I'm running into a problem: the parentheses around the matrix are too big and too far apart from the elements, at least compared to the regular `\pmatrix`. Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}    
\begin{document}

AMSMath:

\[ \begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 2 & 3 \\
 4 & 5 & 6
\end{pmatrix} \]

TikZ:

\[ \begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[matrix of math nodes,left delimiter=(,right delimiter=)] (m) {
 1 & 2 & 3 \\
 4 & 5 & 6 \\ }; \end{tikzpicture} \]

TikZ without delimiters + AMSMath:

\[ \begin{pmatrix} \begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[matrix of math nodes] (m) {
 1 & 2 & 3 \\
 4 & 5 & 6 \\ }; \end{tikzpicture} \end{pmatrix} \]

\end{document}
```

If I don't use TikZ delimiters and put everything inside a `\pmatrix`, like in the third example, the parentheses look slightly different but they're still too big. The same thing happens with brackets. Is there a way around this?

[image]

Comment: add `draw,nodes=draw` to your matrices and start adjusting inner and outer seps

Comment: @percusse: the problem is that reducing inner sep shrinks not only the bounding box of the whole matrix (which is what I want) but also the bounding boxes of the individual numbers, making them be closer together (which is what I don't want). Can they be controlled separately? I'm looking at the TikZ-PGF manual and can't find anything about this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The delimiters can be shifted through the styles `every (left|right) delimiter`:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}% (a5paper for smaller image width)
\usepackage{amsmath,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}

AMSMath:

\[ \begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 2 & 3 \\
 4 & 5 & 6
\end{pmatrix} \]

TikZ:

\[
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
    every left delimiter/.style={xshift=.75em},
    every right delimiter/.style={xshift=-.75em},
  ]
    \matrix[
      matrix of math nodes,
      left delimiter=(,
      right delimiter=),
    ] (m) {
      1 & 2 & 3 \\
      4 & 5 & 6 \\
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}
\]

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Also applying `inner sep=1.5pt, column sep=6pt, row sep=2pt,` options to `\matrix` makes it closed to the `pmatrix`.

Comment: Thank you! What ended up working best is a combination of this and @Ignasi's answer. I used an x/yshift of `.4em` and a column sep of `3.5pt` and it looks almost identical to the default matrix.

Answer (score 9):

A `TikZ matrix` is a `node` which contains other nodes, so the distance between nodes and brackets is twice the `inner sep` one due to internal nodes and the second is the `inner sep` between nodes and matrix border.

You can fix a matrix-node inner sep to 0pt and later on fix another `inner sep` for nodes (see [How to fix a certain distance between a TikZ matrix border and its nodes?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86873/how-to-fix-a-certain-distance-between-a-tikz-matrix-border-and-its-nodes)).

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}% (a5paper for smaller image width)
\usepackage{amsmath,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}

AMSMath:

\[ \begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 2 & 3 \\
 4 & 5 & 6
\end{pmatrix} \]

TikZ: default inner sep

\[
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix[draw, %<- just used to show differences
      matrix of math nodes,
      left delimiter=(,
      right delimiter=),
    ] (m) {
      1 & 2 & 3 \\
      4 & 5 & 6 \\
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}
\]

TikZ: matrix inner sep = 0pt

\[
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix[draw, %<- just used to show differences
      inner sep=0pt, %<- set inner sep for all nodes 
      nodes={inner sep=.3333em}, %<- set another inner sep for inner nodes
      matrix of math nodes,
      left delimiter=(,
      right delimiter=),
    ] (m) {
      1 & 2 & 3 \\
      4 & 5 & 6 \\
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

perhaps you would like to reduce the inner sep a bit more, as below it gives

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}    
\begin{document}

AMSMath:

\[ \begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 2 & 3 \\
 4 & 5 & 6
\end{pmatrix} \]

TikZ:

\[ \begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[matrix of math nodes,left delimiter=(,right delimiter=),
outer sep = 0pt,inner sep=2pt] (m) {
 1 & 2 & 3 \\
 4 & 5 & 6 \\ }; \end{tikzpicture} \]

TikZ without delimiters + AMSMath:

\[ \begin{pmatrix} \begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[matrix of math nodes] (m) {
 1 & 2 & 3 \\
 4 & 5 & 6 \\ }; \end{tikzpicture} \end{pmatrix} \]

\end{document}
```

Comment: This isn't quite right, though. It just makes everything closer together instead of just the brackets.

Answer (score 2):

While not convenient to code, a reasonable approximation to the AMSmath version can be obtained by doing these three things:

1. set inner sep of the `tikzpicture` to `-.2pt` or some other appropriate small value;
2. Apply one `\strut` to each row;
3. Make each column alignment `&` double (`&&`), with the desired column separation applied to one entry of each column (here done as `&~~~&` to each column of row 1)

Here is the MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}    
\begin{document}

AMSMath:

\[ \begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 2 & 3 \\
 4 & 5 & 6
\end{pmatrix} \]

TikZ:

\[ \begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=-.2pt]
\matrix[matrix of math nodes,left delimiter=(,right delimiter=)] (m) {
 \strut1 &~~~& 2 &~~~& 3 \\
 \strut4 &&    5 &&    6 \\ }; \end{tikzpicture} \]

\end{document}
```

[image]